# Are there any theorems that can be used to judge if an all-integer programming problem has a feasible solution?

Tags: integer-programming, programming

Are there any theorems that can be used to judge if an all-integer programming problem has a feasible solution?

I am NOT asking if we have any computational solvers that can be used to find a feasible solution to an all-integer programming problem. I think I am asking a more "abstract" question: do we have any theorems to ensure that if the objective function and constraints satisfy some properties, then we must have a feasible solution to an all-integer programming problem?

Comment: In general, this decision problem is NP-complete. I don't think there are useful criteria that are not reducing to exhibiting a feasible solution (for example, if the right member is positive on standard form, setting all the variables to 0 gives a feasible solution). Maybe giving some context on what you are trying to achieve could help...